# Update two row in wordpress sql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to update 2 row in wordpress sql database,
I need change option_name 'stylesheet' value to 'twentyfifteen'
and change option_name 'template' value to 'twentyfifteen'

This code is working:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(" UPDATE $wpdb->options SET option_value = 'twentyfifteen' WHERE option_name = 'template' ");
$wpdb->query(" UPDATE $wpdb->options SET option_value = 'twentyfifteen' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet' ");
```

But I need it in one line, like this but not working with me:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(" UPDATE $wpdb->options SET option_value = 'twentyfifteen' WHERE option_name = 'template',
    UPDATE $wpdb->options SET option_value = 'twentyfifteen' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet' ");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE $wpdb->options 
SET option_value = 'twentyfifteen' 
WHERE option_name in ('template', 'stylesheet')
```

or

```
UPDATE $wpdb->options 
SET option_value = 'twentyfifteen' 
WHERE option_name = 'template'
OR option_name = 'stylesheet'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want update two lines by 1 request, you can use query like that:

```
UPDATE options
SET option_value = "twentyfifteen"
WHERE option_name in ("stylesheet", "template")
```